# Android Studio PNG won't me let open the app

Tags: android, png

Whenever I have to put a PNG in my Android Studio File it says 'Unfortunately App has stopped'.
Why is this?
I'm using Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the image's size. It may be too big and could cause an OutOfMemory error.

When you add an image to your project, it also helps adding it in several sizes (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) for your application to use the best one for your device.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But it works on my Windows PC with the exact same pictures.

Comment: You mean in the virtual machine? It could be that the virtual machine you're using is not the same device as your phisical one. I got one app working on some devices but not another ones, idk.